# show the download percentage progressbar in python

Tags: python, pyqt5, progress-bar, youtube-dl

I am coding about youtube-downloader project so I want to show the download percentage in ProgressBar, but the progressBar dosent show the download percentage and does not fill the bar.  Can somebody help me?
Where is the problem that the progressbar has not any access to downloadbutton?
What change I have to do?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pytube
import re
import os
import subprocess
from pytube.__main__ import YouTube
from Youtube import Ui_MainWindow


class YoutubeMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('Youtube Downloader')
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem('mp3')
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem('avi')
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem('mov')
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem('wmv')
        self.show()
        self.initSignal()

    def initSignal(self) :
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.downloadWork)
        self.ui.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.savePathWork)

    def progress_bar(self,chunk, stream, file_handle, bytes_remaining,previousprogress = 0):
        total_size = stream.filesize
        bytes_download = total_size - bytes_remaining
    
        liveprogress = (int)(bytes_download / total_size * 100)
        if liveprogress > previousprogress:
           previousprogress = liveprogress
           self.ui.progressBar.setValue(liveprogress)
           print(liveprogress)


@pyqtSlot()
def savePathWork(self) :
    fpath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select the Directory')
    self.ui.save_textEdit.setText(fpath)


@pyqtSlot()
def downloadWork(self) :
    url = self.ui.dl_textEdit.text().strip()
    save = self.ui.save_textEdit.text()
    regex = re.compile('^https://www.youtube.com/watch?')

    if url is None or url == '' or not url :
        
        self.ui.dl_textEdit.setFocus(True)
        return None

    if save is None or save == '' or not save :
        
        return None

    if regex.match(url) is not None :
        
        video = pytube.YouTube(url)
        stream = video.streams.all()
        down_dir = self.ui.save_textEdit.text()
        stream[0].download(down_dir)
        yt=YouTube(url.text())
        yt.register_on_progress_callback(self.progress_bar)
        
        if self.ui.checkBox.isChecked() :

    
            oriFiileName = stream[0].default_filename
            newFileName = os.path.splitext(oriFiileName)[0]


            subprocess.call(['ffmpeg','-i',
                os.path.join(down_dir, oriFiileName),
                os.path.join(down_dir, newFileName + '.' + 
                str(self.ui.comboBox.currentText()))
            ])


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    root= YoutubeMain()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" exactly? What behavior do you see? Is there an error of some kind?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your post and fix the indentation of your code by checking the post preview, as right now it's not clear if it doesn't "work" due to implementation or wrong syntax. Read more about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: @tromgy when i run it the progressBar does not show the percentage and fill the bar,some how it doesnt have acsses to download button

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your comment but the syntax are right in my project,i will edit my post now

Comment: It looks like the part of the `progress_bar` function is not indented correctly, starting with `liveprogress = ...` ... or did I screw up when editing your post?

Comment: @mobinhb please take your time to ensure that *all* the code is properly indented; we cannot reproduce your problem if the code you're giving us is not what it's intended: for what we know, you could *believe* that its indentation is correct, but maybe you missed or overlooked something, and we would never know it. That said, I never used pytube, but according to the [docs](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.YouTube.register_on_progress_callback) the arguments used for `progress_bar` are wrong, and it's also unclear what's the purpose of `previousprogress`, since it's used as local.